# gitlab-tcl reconfigure fails at gitlab::selinux module

Tags: gitlab

I have received this error on CentOS 7 while trying to run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[semodule -i /opt/gitlab/embedded/selinux/rhel/7/gitlab-7.2.0-ssh-keygen.pp]'
================================================================================
```

Selinux config was OK, swap was present. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to install `policycoreutils-python` which aren't in dependencies of suggested install and therefore you have to install it yourself by `sudo yum install -y pythoncoreutils-python`. After that `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` runs without a problem.